# Query the salient differences between the neo pragmatistism of Richard Rorty and Hillary Putnam (may they RIP)

Tags: epistemology, pragmatism, rorty, hilary-putnam

While I have over the years read most of what Richard Rorty and Hillary Putnam have “popularly” written/edited [that is aside from their scholarly treatises in academic journals that have for years resided either beyond my physical grasp, or behind pay walls], and much exegesis thereupon; say, from *The Linguistic Turn* and *Philosophy and the Mirror of Nature* [Rorty] and *Reason, Truth and History* [Putnam] forward,  I have often wondered how a true/real contemporary philosopher, one with all the relevant conceptual tools to do the work, would characterize the most salient (metaphysical, epistemological and/or ontological) differences between the two neo-pragmatists. [A related second order questions might be how the two philosophers differed in their assessments of Kant and Wittgenstein.]  Anyone care to take a stab at it?

Comment: I think you are probably more versed in the subtleties of the subject than most our current users. The general takeaway from the Rorty-Putnam debate for outsiders is that Putnam preserves more of scientific motivation, and realism that comes with it, whereas Rorty is a voice of postmodernistic relativism. In a way, it is a replay of the old divide inherent in pragmatism and exhibited already by Peirce and James.

Comment: @Conifold  Interesting that you mention the Pierce-James (pragmatism v [pierce's]pragmaticism) divide here, because that too was not entirely clear to me when I encountered it years ago (though I do recall conceiving it as involving "magnitudes" of realism:  but magnitudes of what metric?).   Moreover, In his "Pragmatism" Putnam uses James, rather than Pierce (or Dewey) as his foil.  And Rorty's hero is Dewey -- though this seems to have as much to do with the substance of Deweys thought and politics, as with Rorty's parents political influences upon young Richard.

Comment: Pragmatists eschew absolutist "proofs" and "certainties", so much, more than usual, turns on judgment calls about value and plausibility. And those often depend on one's personality and background. Peirce judged realism to be the only plausible explanation for the success of science, a sentiment echoed by Putnam's "no miracles" argument. James and Rorty did not, and they were driven by softer cultural concerns. Rorty and Margolis echo James's "truth is what works", the idea Peirce considered "disastrous". One's pragmatism is shaped by design by their pragmatic priorities.

Comment: @Conifold when I say above that " In his "Pragmatism" Putnam uses James, rather than Pierce (or Dewey) as his foil,"  I was referring to his book "Pragmatism," not to his [ever shifting] "brand" of pragmatism[v realism].   Would not Dewey's mean-end analysis/continuum have better suited his project in that it better addressed the "value-plausibilty" balancing that you mention.   So why was his reluctant realism/scientism drawn to James?

Comment: Because he needed a foil rather than a kindred spirit? James traditionally served as a convenient foil from the time of Russell and positivists. Dewey is perfect for Rorty in that he was addressing himself much more to cultural and social policy than science and epistemology, and much more systematically than James. Btw, I did not mean the thematized balancing *in* one's philosophy, rather the shaping *of* personalized philosophy through such balancing, in part unconscious, done behind the scenes.